# Java:Not able to read a Date from excel cell

Tags: java, excel, date, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet, which contains a date in cell D3, This "D3" as value is given in some other cell. I tried to access this date by cell reference but I'm getting a strange number instead.

Below is my code:

```
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
       switch(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) { 
       case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: 
          if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) { 
             if(formatter.formatCellValue(cell).equalsIgnoreCase("D3")){
                CellReference ref=new CellReference(formatter.formatCellValue(cell)); 
                Row r = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow()); 
                Cell c = r.getCell(ref.getCol()); 
                sb.append("\"" + c.getNumericCellValue()+ "\""); 
             } 
          } 
          break;
       case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
          sb.append("\"" + cell.getRichStringCellValue()+ "\""); 
          break;
       default:
          break;
       }
```

My script outputs: `4334`. Why is this so?

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information for _anyone_ to answer it.  Are you using an excel library?  What is 'formatter'?  What are you expecting it to output?  Why are you expecting a numeric cell to contain a non-numeric value?

Comment: It seems that number 4334 corresponds with date "12/11/1911", (twelve of november), is this the date you have put in D3?

Comment: The code gets the numeric value of the cell, try `c.getDateCellValue()`.